# JQuery Validation - Dynamically Required Elements

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a dynamic form in MVC in which some questions may have follow on questions depending on the value selected.
If the follow on question is activated then it becomes 'required' and vice versa.

I can achieve this with JQuery using using classes but am interested in using data attributes as it's more flexible and I can specify exactly which value (of the parent question) triggers the behaviour.

```
<input type="radio" value="1" id="comment1" name="comment" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-followon="true" data-rule-followon-value="1" data-rule-followon-id="comments">Yes              
<input type="radio"  value="0" id="comment0" name="comment">No 

<textarea maxlength="1000" id="comments"></textarea>
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 CSS:

 .hide {
  display: none;
 }

  HTML:

  <textarea maxlength="1000" id="comments" class="hide"></textarea>

 var value= $('input[name=name_of_your_radiobutton]:checked').val();

 if(value== "No")
 {
 $('#comments').removeClass('hide');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said I can already do it css classes.
I'm really after an 'attributes' solution.